# Is it possible to revive GPIO 18 pin?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio

I guess it (pin 18) got burned after me accidentally connecting it to the 12V of the led strip and not the data pin, while the RPI ground and 12V ground were connected too.

I used pigpiod, gpiotest to test the GPIO board for burned pins and got these results: 18th and 17th pins are burned. And I am interested if I can revive the 18th pin somehow?

Comment: My bad, I should have checked first.

Answer (score 2):

It's very, very, very unlikely that you can do anything about it. Or how they say:

> This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker!
>    <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Parrot_sketch)</sup>

Use the Pi while it still works (there is no saying it'll do that forever) and consider it a lesson learned.

Comment: Haha. I hope the other pins would still work.

Comment: Beautiful plumage, the Norwegian Blue